# Astar with time dependent graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, a-star, boost-graph

I have a graph representing a route network - waypoints are vertices and routes are edges. The problem is that there might be regions in between waypoints which cannot be crossed during certain periods. But those regions don't necessarily affect vertices but only edges.

I use time as cost function, so for each vertex (and thus edge) I can get the time of arrival within visitors and/or heuristic. However, as the weightmap is readable, I cannot change the weight of an edge to make it "too long".

On the other hand I cannot create a custom weightmap as I don't know the time of arrival in advance as it depends on the path.

What I found up to know in the forum is to use the heuristic and to set it to inf in case of a "bad" vertex. But what I would need is to select "bad" edges.

Do you have an idea about accessing the currently examined edge within the heuristic (by default its only input is vertex descriptor)?

I know that I could make decisions in the examine_edge visitor , but what should I call in it to let astar know that this edge is bad, and shouldn't be used? Maybe I could create an external boolean "bad edge" property map (for all vertices) and if the current edge is "bad" set the target vertex to true within the examine_edge visitor? This "bad edge" property map could then be accessed by the heuristics.
However, it seems to me that this might not be the best solution.

Any other idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to solving problems like these is to build a new graph whose nodes contain more information than the original nodes. In your case, consider creating a graph with multiple copies of each node, one per different time instant possible. Then, have each edge go between a pair of nodes if there was an edge between the corresponding nodes at the appropriate points in time. For example, edges that are always open will take you from a node at one time point to the corresponding node at a later time point, and edges that are only active at a certain point in time will only be in the graph at those time points.

This has the disadvantage of blowing up the size of the graph, but if you have the option of lazily evaluating the graph this approach might be quite reasonable.